# jQuery Loop for checkboxes

Tags: jquery, loops, checkbox

Currently I've two input fields which updates automatically when I press Update button and I want to add more inputs... but problem is I have to add my input field name in jquery script manually.
Can we add any loop for this? Please help!!

```
Type Comment: <input name="mainComment" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" name="updateComment" value="Update" />

<hr />

<input type="checkbox" class="myCb" name="cb[1]" /><input type="text" name="inv[1]" value="" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCb" name="cb[2]" /><input type="text" name="inv[2]" value="" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='updateComment']").live("click", (function(){
            if($("input[name='cb[1]']").is(":checked")) {
                $("input[name='inv[1]']").val($("input[name='mainComment']").val());
            } else {
                $("input[name='inv[1]']").val("");
            }

            if($("input[name='cb[2]']").is(":checked")) {
                $("input[name='inv[2]']").val($("input[name='mainComment']").val());
            } else {
                $("input[name='inv[2]']").val("");
            }
        }));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated and removed in newer jQuery versions. I would recommend updating your scripts to [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thankyou @empiric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use input's `class name` (`.myCb`) to select the inputs from the DOM and use jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to loop through each inputs.

You can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='updateComment']").on("click", (function(){
          var val = $("input[name='mainComment']").val();
            $('input.myCb').each(function(i) {
             if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).next().val(val);
              } else {
                $(this).next().val('');
              }
            })
          
        
        }));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type Comment: <input name="mainComment" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" name="updateComment" value="Update" />

<hr />

<input type="checkbox" class="myCb" name="cb[1]" /><input type="text" name="inv[1]" value="" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCb" name="cb[2]" /><input type="text" name="inv[2]" value="" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="myCb" name="cb[3]" /><input type="text" name="inv[2]" value="" />
```

Hope this helps!